# Rotate a 2D square by x degrees

Tags: matrices, rotations

Say I have a square represented by the following matrix:

```
0   0
10  0
10  10
0   10
0   0
```

Now, what would I multiply this matrix by to rotate the square (or what ever shape it is) around its **center point** *x* degrees?

Comment: Actually, a simple matrix multiplication won't do. One thing you can do is find the center of that square, translate all your coordinates so that the center is at the origin, apply a rotation matrix (mind the sign of your angles!), and then undo the translation you previously did.

Comment: A more precise way to state the above might be 'Say I have a square represented by the following vectors', because I don't think you mean the numbers above to represent a matrix.  It looks like you are listing 5 (well, 4) vectors, -each- of which you can multiply by a rotation matrix, but not all at  once.